# K8S - Get service list from the service catalog

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, azure, kubernetes

I've a program which needs to get all the available services from the service catalog in my k8s cluster.
Services which implement the *service broker API*.
Is there a way to achieve it via code?
https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/extend-kubernetes/service-catalog/

I see that I need the following

```
ClusterServiceClass
ServiceBinding
ServiceBindingUsage
ServiceInstance
```

https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/extend-kubernetes/service-catalog/#architecture

But how can I achieve that via kubectl on nodejs